# How to reset the ilo5 factory generated password using API ? or ilorest Tool from remote machine?

Tags: passwords

I have multiple HPE gen10 Server which has ILO5 license.
Now I want to manage the server from remote system using API or HP ilorest Tool, but to authenticate it require password of user administrator & it comes as tag on the server and its very tedious task to note down the password & reset if you have 100 to 200 servers.

Does anyone know how I can reset the password without having old one? from remote system.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method available to reset the password...but you can ask HPE to set the password as per your requirement during the purchase of order.